see Role assignments User
currently we are using PIM to assign role's to our admin users. but somehow we have one user who doesn’t have the role Exchange Admin who can still manage shared mailbox delegations. we can’t find how he is allowed to do this. so I was hoping someone could give me a PowerShell script to check which roles he has assigned or to check how he is allowed to do so. we checked our PIM role's in Entra and we checked our roles in exchange but there is no role available to him which allows him to change shared mailbox settings. I hope somebody can give me a PowerShell script which showcases the assigned roles or which showcases the way he is possible to do these changes.

The issue may not be ROLE.  Somebody could of given the person access by the user name on the folder/file.

Locate one of the mailboxes that the user can unexpectedly manage, review the ACL on that mailbox/folder, then figure out (trial by elimination) which group memberships he has that satisfies any appropriate ACE's on the mailbox/folder

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
